# Protobuf-Net Objects containing DataTables

Tags: protobuf-net

I am using the DataTable ProtoRead/ProtoWrite to serialize DataTables and it works fine. My problem is if I have a business object that has a DataTable for a field, how do I tell the runtime model to use the specific serialization routine for a DataTable?

Thanks.

Comment: Interesting question; are you using `protobuf-net-data` from Nuget? I honestly can't say I've tried hooking both together at the same time, so I'd have to take a look. The alternative, of course, is to serialize the `DataTable` first and store it in a `byte[]` property; or have a `byte[]` *shim* property that does the serialize/deserialize when requested.